# Why are vapours of xenon hexafluoride coloured?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, color, noble-gases

According to [Wikipedia,](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenon_hexafluoride)

> [...] It is a colorless solid that readily sublimes into intensely yellow vapors.

It is clear from the above statement that $\ce{XeF6}$ is colourless in solid form. But why should it be coloured when it converts into vapour form?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82350/what-is-the-molecular-structure-of-xenon-hexafluoride https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50187/what-is-hybridisation-of-xef6-in-solid-state

Comment: Bottom line is it depolymerises.

Comment: There is nothing unusual about vapors of elements/compounds appearing colored. It is a common phenomenon. Potassium is a silvery white metal but its vapors appear green! Sodium also shows colored vapor. People have spent their trying to understand the structure of xenon hexafluoride.

Comment: Related for oxygen: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15035/does-o2-have-a-color-in-the-gas-phase Oxygen is colorless at gaseous state but is slightly colored in liquid and solid state.

Comment: @NilayGhosh, This oxygen issue is perhaps a different phenomenon. It is simply a concentration effect (Beer's law). Just like  heavy water appear blue when viewed in a very long path length tube but in an ordinary beaker it is colorless pure white liquid. Xenon hexafluoride is complicated in the sense that there must be a change in the nature of bonding in the solid phase and gas phase. Just like potassium and sodium vapor. One would never assume that potassium has a beautiful green vapor.

Comment: H2O is definitely blue in large quantities by transmitted light. D2O is colorless because the stretching frequency overtones do not reach into the visible.

Comment: O2 gas is definitely colorless. How long a path is necessary to see that? There are condensed species in the liquid and various solid phases.